Swift + macOS: Task statement crash the app
I'm working on an app for macOS. Until somedays ago I was using completion handler-based-function for consuming some endpoints, but then I decided to switch to async/await, so I started using the Task statement to make some async work.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(model.title)
                .padding()
        }
        .onAppear {
            Task {
                do {
                    let a = try await model.load()
                    print(a)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

After compiling and running the app crashed: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

At the beggining I thought there was something wrong with my async function, but after checking I can confirm it is ok. Then I removed the contents from the Task statement like this:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(model.title)
                .padding()
        }
        .onAppear {
            Task {
            }
        }
    }
}

After compiling and running it, the problem persists. So there's something wrong with the Task statement.
One important fact is that Task is running well on iOS projects with same Xcode version.
Does anyone know what the problem is? I'm using:

Xcode Version 13.2.1 (13C100)
Apple Swift version 5.5.2
macOS Big Sur 11.7.10
MacBook Pro Retina Display 15' Late 2013

I'm expecting to make this work using the Task statement.
Please, let me know if you need me to provide more information about this error.
EDIT Dec 24, 2024.
I'm adding this edit since StackOverflow needs me to provide a reproducible example:
The thing is that any macOS project that has Task{} statement will crash, and I'm almost convinced that is related to my system, or in other words, it won't crash on other machines.
I have created a default macOS Xcode project, I didn't add any other code than a Task{} statement in a .onAppear modifier from the default view that comes with the default project, and the app crashes, but runs well after removing that Task{} statement. Just as simple like that. Obviously, in my real project I have some async calls in the Task{}, but here I'm simplifying the example isolating the problem: the Task{} statement.
You can clone this repo I created for this issue https://gitlab.com/danielost/testmacosapp .
I also uploaded this video for you to watch when the app crashes: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lym3Ej6ja2z7b08T46Cv-3MluIOLtmWN/view?usp=sharing
Even though I have the feeling that this repo will run well for you, but it crashes in my machine, why?
EDIT Dec 27, 2024.
Ok guys, I was able to make it work: The thing is that when I create a new Xcode macOS app project it's created with a deployment target of the current macOS version, 11.7 in my case.
In the Project -> Deployment target section, macOS deployment target field is set to "11.7", but after opening the dropdown menu to see the other available deployment targets "11.7" is not actually an option the list:
deployment target dropdown
So that made think that maybe there are some files missing for the deployment target 11.7 or that maybe Xcode just uses that version (just because it's my current OS version) without checking if it has the files for supporting concurrency for that version, don't know, it's my assumption.
So, what I did was selecting the most recent deployment target for macOS Big Sur in that dropdown: 11.5, then cleaned the build folder and run the app: it didn't crash.
It would be interesting to know why it crashes with 11.7 as deployment target, but I consider this issue solved.
Thank you.

Don't use Task within .onAppear; just use .task {}.  Set an exception breakpoint to try and find where the crash is occurring

Code inside a Task block runs on a background thread by default. The most likely cause of a crash is that you're doing some sort of UI code inside your Task. What does your model.load() function do?

@DuncanC Is there any document point out that Task block runs on a background thread by default? as I read in Apple docs that it inherits the priority and actor context of the caller

You don’t need to guess. Look at the stack trace and it may well show you the call tree that lead to the crash. Click on your methods in that stack trace and it show you where it crashed. Also, usually the console shows illuminating messages. What messages, if any, are shown in the Xcode console?

@DuncanC – A Task {…} will run on the main actor if invoked from the main actor, and onAppear is isolated to the main actor. Insert a MainActor.preconditionIsolated() to verify that. The issue undoubtedly rests elsewhere. Maybe model.title is an implicitly unwrapped optional that is nil. We can only guess in the absence of more debugging info or a MRE.

@daniel86 – Try removing the Task {} altogether and see if it still crashes.

@Paulw11 .task{} is supported from macOS 12 onwards, I'm with macOS 11. And the app crashes just by putting an empty Task{}, no need to do anything inside of it.

@DuncanC I'm not doing anything related to UI inside Task{}, also it crashes just by putting that statement in the code without any code inside the curly braces. model.load() makes a call using URLSession, but as I said, it stills crashes even with onlyt Task{}

@Rob There's no any methods: i created a brand new macOS application, I didn't add any other code than just  a Task{} statement (without any code inside it) in the onAppear{} modifier  and it crashes. The app only runs well by removing the Task{}

@daniel86 This could very well be a bug in macOS 11.7. Keep in mind that the version of Xcode and macOS that you are using are very old and if your goal is to put an app into the App Store, you will need newer versions which means you will probably need a newer Mac that supports those newer versions.
